# Incorrect data_files location using distutils

Tags: python, distutils

The [distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) specifies that when the target directory for data_files is a relative path, the files will be installed relative to `sys.prefix`. On my system (Linux Mint), this is `/usr`; however, the data_files are instead installing to `/usr/local`.

How can I correct this without losing cross-platform support?

Answer (score 2):

This is an Ubuntu / Linux mint related issue, they default to `/usr/local` instead of `/usr`.

[1] http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1121501

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to 1) install someone else's program or 2) write a setup.py yourself?

If 1), are you appending `--prefix=/usr/local` when invoking `python setup.py`? If so, installation prefix will become `/usr/local`, to which the data files will be installed relative.

If 2), check out the value of `sys.prefix` & `sys.exec_prefix` (or post the relating part of your setup.py).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check the sys.prefix for the Python you use to run the setup script.

Second, check distutils configuration files (one is distutils.cfg in the Python standard library directory (yuck, I know), another is ~/.pydistutils.cfg, the last is the optional setup.cfg that follows setup.py).